# Is this an example of destructuring assignment?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, object

Going through React, I was wondering why the method handlechange wasn't coded as the following. As I've tried both seem to work. Wondering if this is a destructuring assignement.

```
 handleCelsiusChange(temperature) {
    this.setState({scale: 'c', temperature: temperature});
  }
```

original code:

```
 constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.handleCelsiusChange = this.handleCelsiusChange.bind(this);
    this.handleFahrenheitChange = this.handleFahrenheitChange.bind(this);
    this.state = {temperature: '', scale: 'c'};
  }

  handleCelsiusChange(temperature) {
    this.setState({scale: 'c', temperature});
  }

  handleFahrenheitChange(temperature) {
    this.setState({scale: 'f', temperature});
  }
```

Code takend from [reactJs](http://%20handleCelsiusChange(temperature)%20%7B%20%20%20%20%20this.setState(%7Bscale:%20'c',%20temperature%7D);%20%20%20%7D)

Comment: No, it's not... Just passing an object as an argument to a function.

Comment: are you referring to changing `temperature: temperature` to just `temperature`? That's not desctructuring it's [short-hand property names](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#Method_definitions)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference between

```
 handleCelsiusChange(temperature) {
    this.setState({scale: 'c', temperature: temperature});
  }
```

and

```
  handleCelsiusChange(temperature) {
    this.setState({scale: 'c', temperature});
  }
```

is that second use shorter notation which became available in ECMAScript 2015. You may see description with samples [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer)